# Changing select will change another SELECT with same previous value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

i need help with my code. I have a lot of Select inputs

```
<select title="" name="width[]">
<option value="8">3mm</option>
<option value="1">10mm</option>
<option selected="" value="4">18mm</option>
</select>
```

and when I change one of them I need to change values in all selects where was same value.

for example

```
1. select with value 8
2. select with value 8
3. select with value 4
4. select with value 8
5. select with value 4
```

and when I change second SELECT with value 8 to value 1, I need to change 1. and 4. SELECTs and change their values to 1.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This question does not provide any tried codes and expect others to solve the problem (i.e. do-it-for-me)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sv3399o7/5/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".ddl").change(function() {  
var ddl1=$(this);   
$('select[id^=begin_]').each(function(){
    var DDLId=$(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + DDLId + ' option').each(function(){              

    if ($(this).val() == ddl1.val()) 
    {               
        $(this).val(ddl1.val()).attr('selected','selected');
    }

  });

  });   
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sv3399o7/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot but there is one problem.. your code is changing all select, but I need to change only selects with same value.

Comment: Please provide your HTML for better result

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sv3399o7/2/   When I change 18mm to 3mm all 18mm Selects will change, no 10mm and 3mm

Comment: If the above code suitable your needs,please accept as answer.

Comment: hello, there is still this problem. When I change Select input where value is 10mm i need change only Select inputs where value is 10mm. Your code is still changing all Select inputs. Selected attribute in html is only for load page on first time. if on page are 50 select inputs and user select in 25 inputs value 8mm and then he change it to 10mm it will change value only in this 25 selects where is 8mm value.

Comment: Hey have you tried my demo,in demo second `dropdown` have `20mm` which is not exist in `first dropdown`.When we choose `20mm` from second ddl their is no change happen in first ddl.How can you say its not working or issue.

Comment: i need the same values in all dropdown and when I change for example forth dropdown value to 8mm where was value 10mm, jquery find all Select dropdow where was 10mm and change it to 8mm